# Simple Solutions to Homogeneous Recursions

Tags: recurrence-relations

Let $b_n - 2b_{n-2} + b_{n-3} = 0$ be a linear homogeneous recursion.  I was able to solve this using a characteristic equation but deriving coefficients became incredibly messy.  However, I thought this should be a very simple recursion to solve.  Does anyone have alternative suggestions for how to avoid messy algebra?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the technique in Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html). Define the generating function $B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n$, and write:
$$
b_{n + 3} - 2 b_{n + 1} + b_n = 0
$$
Then:
$$
\frac{B(z) - b_0 - b_1 z - b_2 z^2}{z^3} 
  - 2 \frac{B(z) - b_0}{z}
  + B(z) = 0
$$
This gives as partial fractions:
$$
B(z) = \frac{2 b_0 - b_1 - b_2 + (3 b_0 - b_1 - 2 b_2) z}{1 - z - z^2}
         - \frac{b_0 -  b_1 - b_2}{1 - z}
$$
Now:
$$
\frac{z}{1 - z - z^2}
$$
is the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers $F_n$, while
$$
\frac{1}{1 - z - z^2}
$$
turns out to be the generating function for the Fibonacci numbers displaced by 1, $F_{n + 1}$. So:
$$
b_n = (3 b_0 - b_1 - 2 b_2) F_n 
        + (2 b_0 - b_1 - b_2) F_{n + 1}
        - (b_0 -  b_1 - b_2)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite sure how to follow your steps.

Comment: If $B(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n$, for $\sum_{n \ge 0} b_{n + 2} z^2$ you have to get rid of $b_0 + b_1 z$ and divide by $z^2$, giving $(B(z) - b_0 - b_1 z) / z^2$.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain a solution using this method with only initial conditions b1 = 1 and b2 = 2?

Comment: @user71443, just replace those values at the beginning. Having numbers probably simplifies the work quite a bit. Or replace in the final expression... but you need three values to fix the solution.

Comment: Yes, I suppose it was not meant to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of:
$$b_n-b_{n-1} = -(b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}) + (b_{n-2}-b_{n-3}) $$
This will lead you to a slightly simpler and more elegant solution.

Comment: I am unsure how to use characteristics to approach this one, but it is interesting.

Comment: Define $c_n=b_n-b_{n-1}$.

Comment: And now it is an equation with auxiliary $x^2 + x - 1$ which has roots $\phi$ and -$\phi$

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. And you can get $b_n$ from $c_n$ by summation.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!!

Comment: Hope it comes out pretty ...

Comment: It did not, I realized that I need to use initial conditions $b_1 = 1$ and $b_2 = 2$ to solve it but these cannot be used for c as defined.

Comment: I think it should be possible by calculating the first elements of $c_n$ starting from $b_2-b_1$. I'll give it a try as soon as I have some time.

Comment: It's the same as with the $b_n$ where you need a third initial element, as vonbrand pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is just a worked out version of my previous answer. My intention is to show that in this case the solution can also be found without the need to deal with a third order polynomial.

We have
$$b_n = 2b_{n-2} - b_{n-3},\quad n=0,1,2,... $$
The initial conditions $b_{-3}, b_{-2}, b_{-1}$ must be given. We can rewrite the recurrence as follows:
$$b_n - b_{n-1} = -(b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}) + (b_{n-2}-b_{n-3})$$
Defining $c_n=b_n-b_{n-1}$ we get
$$c_n = -c_{n-1}+c_{n-2}$$
with initial conditions $c_{-1}=b_{-1}-b_{-2}$ and $c_{-2}=b_{-2}-b_{-3}$. We obtain the generating function
$$C(z) = \frac{c_{-1}z - (c_{-1}-c_{-2})z^2}{z^2+z-1} = \frac{a_1z}{z-z_1} + \frac{a_2z}{z-z_2}$$ with
$$ z_1 = \frac{-1+\sqrt{5}}{2},z_2 = \frac{-1-\sqrt{5}}{2},
a_1=\frac{c_{-1}-(c_{-1}-c_{-2})z_1}{z_1-z_2},
a_2=\frac{c_{-1}-(c_{-1}-c_{-2})z_2}{z_2-z_1}$$
The resulting sequence is
$$c_n = a_1z_1^n + a_2z_2^n, \quad n=0,1,2,...$$
Finally, we can obtain the sequence $b_n$ by summing over $c_n$:
$$b_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k + b_{-1} =
a_1\frac{1-z_1^{n+1}}{1-z_1} + a_2\frac{1-z_2^{n+1}}{1-z_2} + b_{-1}, \quad n=0,1,2,...$$